# how to solve this error Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("Welcome", null) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i would like to acces to my Welcome page when clicking on the login button, here is what i tried to implement :

the routes i have integrated, only the welcome route doesn't work

```
    routes: {
    'SignIn':(context)=>SignInScreen(),
     'SignUp':(context)=>SignUpScreen(),
     'Home':(context)=>HomeScreen(),
     'welcome':(context)=>Welcome(),
  },
```

and here is where i call the welcome page

```
     RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Welcome');
              },
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                'LOG IN',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Welcome');
```

into this:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'welcome');
```

The name of the route in the `pushNamed()` argument should be the same as the name inside `routes`